# Return variable from python multi-process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

My original code looks similar to this toy example. It creates two random matrices, multiplies them and saves the output in a list.

```
import numpy as np

n = 100
N = 10
out = [1] * N

for i in range(0, N):

    A = np.random.rand(n, n)
    B = np.random.rand(n, n)

    out[i] = A * B
```

Now I am trying to parallelize this loop using multiprocessing. I define the function g and run_complex_operations in defs.py

```
import numpy as np
    
def g(n):
    A = np.random.rand(n, n)
    B = np.random.rand(n, n)

    C = A * B


def run_complex_operations(operation, input, pool):
    pool.map(operation, input)
    print(input)
```

and parallelize the code as follows:

```
import defs   
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

n = 100
N = 10
l = [n] * N

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes_pool = mp.Pool(N)
    defs.run_complex_operations(defs.g, range(N), processes_pool)
```

My question is: How can I save the resulting matrix C in each iteration in the list out, so that I end up with a list of 10 matrices?

**Update:**

Solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the keyword `return` from [python functions tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) in python returns its parameter back to the caller, you can use it to return the result of the function back to out

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def g(n):
    A = np.random.rand(n, n)
    B = np.random.rand(n, n)

    return A * B

def run_complex_operations(operation, input, pool):
    result = pool.map(operation, input)
    print(input)
    return result

n = 100
N = 10
l = [n] * N

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes_pool = mp.Pool(N)
    out = run_complex_operations(g, range(N), processes_pool)
    print(len(out))  # 10
```

Edit: a small trick, if you instead want to fill `l` variable with the output your can use inplace assignment of lists as follows.

```py
l[:] = run_complex_operations(g, range(N), processes_pool)
```

which will take the returns of the function and put each element returned to an index in the list, .... but predefining `l` has no real benefit over `l = run_complex_operations...`

small note, you are doing an element-wise multiplication, not matrix multiplication, you should use `A @ B` for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I run your code, I get an error message. Please see the update in my question for the exact code I run and the error message.

Comment: @eigenvector all the functions should be modified to `return` the result, as in my answer, the last line must contain `return` and then what you want to return after it in every function.

Comment: I overlooked that. Now it's working. Thank you!